# Symfony Class Not Found when all vendors are installed

Tags: symfony

Symfony can't find any classes, for example at AppKernel.php, I have this error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found in /app/app/AppKernel.php on line 6
```

All vendors are correctly installed, the cache are cleared, and the folder var/ has the right permissions.
Do you know where it can come from ? 
My version of symfony is 2.8.

Comment: how did you install Symfony?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs By using composer (require "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*")

Comment: I think you've installed it incorrectly, should be running following the steps outlined here: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup.html

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs it's not a fresh project, it's a big one I am trying to port to docker. I already did all the obvious steps and everything seems to work fine except this.

Comment: Did you run a "composer dump-autoload" somewhere along the line?  Might be useful to take a look at the composer generated autoload files.

Comment: Yes I did. I solved the issue,the problem was that the require autoload was not included in the app_dev.php ...